# Schema Title and ItemSchema Criterias are not fetching components

Tags: broker

I need to query the components based on a particular schema and I tried to use both SchemaTitle as well as ItemSchema criteria for same but I am not getting any results. I have published DCPs and having entry of my schema in schema table and have an entry in Component and CP tables as well. Any help will be appreciated. I am using Tridion 2013 SP1
code snippet is below:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Your code looks correct.  Are the components published to the correct CD target?  Also, are they published from the publication you're querying, I.e. 55?

Comment: Yes Nickoli, I checked the Broker DB as well as Storage config. If I am directly fetching a CP for a component with same schema then its getting fetched. But Criteria code is not working. While Querying , the Criterias are coming as null and hence its giving null results. There is no error coming.

Comment: At this point I would enable SQL logging with Hibernate and see what the DB query is being generated.  Then I would run the DB query directly via SQL Manager and see what's in the query regarding schema where it includes the schema id/name (eliminate conditions in the WHERE clause until you find the culprit), and this should give you a hint on what's going wrong.  Here is how to enable sql logging: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/3448/159

Comment: It was a storage config issue. Thanks for help Nickoli.

Comment: Can you share the details of what was wrong in your config as an Answer to this question so that we can close the case?

Comment: default storage was not pointing to db.