# How can i retrieve components using broker query with sort parameter over optional metafield

Tags: content-delivery, broker, query

I have a requirement to sort on optional custom date for components. I have 25 components matching criteria and 1 component with published date (metadata field) empty, but its returns only 24 components.if i remove sortparameter , then it returns all 25 components.I am using below broker query to retrieve components with sortparameter:-

```
            Query query = new Query();
            Criteria TopNewsArticleCriteria = null;
            PublicationCriteria pubCriteria = new PublicationCriteria(pubID);
            ItemSchemaCriteria IsArticle = new ItemSchemaCriteria(articleID);
            TaxonomyKeywordCriteria taxonomyKeywordCriteria = new TaxonomyKeywordCriteria(strTaxnomyURI, strTaxKeywordURI, false);
            AndCriteria compCriteria = new AndCriteria(pubCriteria, IsArticle);
            AndCriteria KeywordCriteria = new AndCriteria(taxonomyKeywordCriteria, compCriteria);
            TopNewsArticleCriteria = KeywordCriteria;
            query.Criteria = TopNewsArticleCriteria ;

        //First Criteria Sort by published date Meta
        CustomMetaKeyColumn customMetaKeyColumnDate = new CustomMetaKeyColumn("Published_Date", MetadataType.DATE);
        query.AddSorting(new SortParameter(customMetaKeyColumnDate, SortParameter.Descending));

        query.AddSorting(sortParameter);


        string[] ItemUris = query.ExecuteQuery();
        results = ItemUris.ToList();
```

I am not able to fetch components published with empty metadatafield (Published_Date="").
I tried to enable Sql logging as suggested in post ([Broker Query with sort criteria over optional field](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/11441/broker-query-with-sort-criteria-over-optional-field)) and tried executing the logged sql. please find the below query got generated:-

select distinct itemmeta0_.PUBLICATION_ID as col_0_0_, itemmeta0_.ITEM_REFERENCE_ID as col_1_0_, itemmeta0_.ITEM_TYPE as col_2_0_, 
 custommeta3_.KEY_DATE_VALUE as col_3_0_, itemmeta0_.LAST_PUBLISHED_DATE as col_4_0_ from ITEMS itemmeta0_ 
 cross join ITEM_CATEGORIES_AND_KEYWORDS relatedkey1_ cross join COMPONENT componentm2_ 
 inner join ITEMS componentm2_1_ on componentm2_.PUBLICATION_ID=componentm2_1_.PUBLICATION_ID 
 and componentm2_.ITEM_REFERENCE_ID=componentm2_1_.ITEM_REFERENCE_ID cross join CUSTOM_META custommeta3_ 
 where itemmeta0_.ITEM_REFERENCE_ID=relatedkey1_.ITEM_REFERENCE_ID and itemmeta0_.PUBLICATION_ID=relatedkey1_.PUBLICATION_ID 
 and relatedkey1_.KEYWORD_ID=8316 and relatedkey1_.TAXONOMY_ID=1528 and relatedkey1_.PUBLICATION_ID=55 and itemmeta0_.PUBLICATION_ID=55 
 and itemmeta0_.ITEM_REFERENCE_ID=componentm2_.ITEM_REFERENCE_ID and itemmeta0_.PUBLICATION_ID=componentm2_.PUBLICATION_ID 
 and componentm2_.SCHEMA_ID=8228 and custommeta3_.PUBLICATION_ID=itemmeta0_.PUBLICATION_ID and custommeta3_.ITEM_ID=itemmeta0_.ITEM_REFERENCE_ID 
 and custommeta3_.ITEM_TYPE=itemmeta0_.ITEM_TYPE and custommeta3_.KEY_NAME='Published_Date' order by custommeta3_.KEY_DATE_VALUE DESC

which return only 24 components.

further debuging, i tried executing below query to see if CUSTOM_META table has a record with empty field or not:-

select * from CUSTOM_META where CUSTOM_META.KEY_NAME='Published_Date' and PUBLICATION_ID = 55

which didn't return the component with empty metadata field,

It looks like its a crossjoin ( not left join) on CUSTOM_META table which is causing problem.

Is there a way to retrieve components with sortparameter on optional metadata fields?